# How can i get the value of primary_value in activerecord has_many definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: books
# id           :integer 
# owner_id     :integer

# Table name: users
# id           :integer
# name         :string

# Table name: shared_books_records
# user_id      :integer
# book_id      :integer

books
id: 1, owner_id: 1 # jack
id: 2, owner_id: 2 # tom
id: 3, owner_id: 1 # jack

users
id: 1, name: "jack"
id: 2, name: "tom"
```

Jack has two books and Tom has one book.

```
shared_books_records
user_id: 1, book_id: 2
```

So jack borrowed the tom's book. Now jack should have 3 books.

```
class User
  def all_books
    join_sql = <<-SQL.squish!
      LEFT OUTER JOIN shared_books_records
        ON shared_books_records.user_id = books.assignee_id
    SQL
    condition = <<-SQL.squish!
       books.owner_id = :user_id OR 
       shared_books_records.user_id = user_id
    SQL

    Book.joins(join_sql).where(condition, user_id: id)
  end
end
```

I think it's not very good, `activerecord` association is better. So I want to redefine it.

```
has_many :all_books, 
         -> { 
           primary_key_value = xxxx    # I want to get this value

           join_sql = <<-SQL.squish!
             LEFT OUTER JOIN shared_books_records
               ON shared_books_records.user_id = books.assignee_id
           SQL

           condition = <<-SQL.squish!
             books.owner_id = :user_id OR 
             shared_books_records.user_id = user_id
           SQL

           joins(join_sql).unscope(:where).where(condition, user_id: primary_key_value)
         }, 
         class_name: Book, foreign_key: :owner_id
```

But I don't know how to get the value of `primary_key` in the scope.

---

My solution

```
has_many :all_books, 
     -> (user) { 
       primary_key_value = user.id    # I want to get this value

       join_sql = <<-SQL.squish!
         LEFT OUTER JOIN shared_books_records
           ON shared_books_records.user_id = books.assignee_id
       SQL

       condition = <<-SQL.squish!
         books.owner_id = :user_id OR 
         shared_books_records.user_id = :user_id
       SQL

       joins(join_sql).unscope(:where).where(condition, user_id: primary_key_value)
     }, 
     class_name: Book, foreign_key: :owner_id
```

Comment: has_many :all_books, class_name: Book, foreign_key: :owner_id this will return all the columns from table and it includes primary_key... so current_user.all_books will return everything for you

Answer (score 0):

To get all books you can simply do like this

```
class User
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :books, through: :user_books
end

class UserBook
  belongs_to :books
  belongs_to :users
end

class Book
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :users, through: :user_books
end

# Table name: books
# id           :integer 
# owner_id     :integer

# Table name: users
# id           :integer

# Table name: user_books (previously shared_books_record)
# user_id      :integer
# book_id      :integer


def all_ books
  #lets say id has value for user_id
  user = User.find(id)
  all_books = user.books #this should return an array of all books which belongs to the current user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :books, through: :user_books
end

class UserBook
  belongs_to :books
  belongs_to :users
end

class Book
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :users, through: :user_books
end
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered poor-quality content on Stack Overflow. Please provide information about *why* this answers the question.